# Knockout js template not showing

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Hello I have a knockout js template for deleting and editing.
This is the script

```
 <script id="RRitemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>            
        <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: Abbreviation"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lender"></td>



        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <div data-bind="if: status() > 0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.editItem">Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="if: status() < 1">
                <span data-bind="text: status_description"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="RReditTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            <select id="selected_currency_local" class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="options: $root.availableCurrencies,
                    optionsText: 'Abbreviation',
                    value: $parent.selectedCurrencyLocal,
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
            </select>
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-left" data-bind="value: lender" />
        </td>

        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.acceptItemEdit">Accept</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $parent.cancelItemEdit">Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Here is a model where the template should open.

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Modal dialog for allowing the user to edit his/her open loans data. -->

<div data-bind="bootstrapShowModal: modalThirdParty" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--
            <div class="modal-header"> 
                <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-bind="click: hideModalEditRiskRating">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php /*echo lang("myprofile_pinfo_user_risk_rate"); */?></h4>
            </div>
            -->       
            <div class="modal-body" data-bind="with: userOpenLoan">
                <form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="pull-left">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">3rd party risk raters.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: $root.saveUserOpenLoanData">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <?php echo lang("register_save"); ?>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: $root.hideModalThirdParty">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> <?php echo lang("login_close"); ?>
                    </button>
                    <p/>
                    <p/>
                </div>

                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                    <!-- <caption class="text-left"><p><strong><?php echo lang("myprofile_pinfo_user_risk_rate"); ?></strong></p></caption> -->
                    <thead> 
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center tbl_col_width">Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center tbl_col_width">Value</th>
                            <th class="text-center tbl_col_width"><?php echo lang("myprofile_openloan_do_business"); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse, foreach: items}"></tbody>

                </table>
                </div> <!-- table-responsive -->

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: addItem">New Item</button> 

            </form> <!-- Form Horizontal -->

            </div> <!-- modal-body -->
            <!--
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the knockout js file where I am calling this function and also getting the data from the database.

```
 var ThirdPartyRRViewModel = function(parent, items) {
            var root = parent;
            var self = this;

            this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

            this.selectedItem = ko.observable();

            /* Observable for storing the data of currency select. */
            self.selectedCurrencyLocal = ko.observable();

            this.addItem = function() {
                var d = new Date();
                var day = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                var target_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

                $.each(root.availableCurrencies(), function (index, currencyItem) {
                    if (currencyItem.ID == root.userRiskRate().Currency) {
                        self.selectedCurrencyLocal(currencyItem);
                    }
                });
                var newLoan = {"ID":0, "ORIG_ID":0, "Currency":self.selectedCurrencyLocal().ID, "Abbreviation":self.selectedCurrencyLocal().Abbreviation, 
                               "Amount":0, "date_borrowed":target_date, "monthly_amortization":0, "lender":"lender name", 
                               "final_due_date":target_date, "status":1, "status_description":"Active"};

                var newItem = new Item(newLoan);
                self.items.push(newItem);
                self.selectedItem(newItem);
            };

            this.deleteItem = function(itemToDelete) {
                /* If ORIG_ID is greater than > 0, useropenloan row has been read from the database 
                   and can not be removed, but cancelled. */
                if (itemToDelete.ORIG_ID() > 0) {
                    itemToDelete.status(-1); /* Indicates to server that this item should be updated to cancelled. */ 
                    itemToDelete.status_description('Will be cancelled');
                    itemToDelete.itemIsEdited(1);
                } else {
                     self.items.remove(itemToDelete);
                }
                self.selectedItem(null);
            };

            this.editItem = function(item) {
                $.each(root.availableCurrencies(), function (index, currencyItem) {
                    if (currencyItem.ID == item.Currency()) {
                        self.selectedCurrencyLocal(currencyItem);
                    }
                });
                self.selectedItem(item);
            };

            this.acceptItemEdit = function() {
                self.selectedItem().Currency(self.selectedCurrencyLocal().ID);
                self.selectedItem().Abbreviation(self.selectedCurrencyLocal().Abbreviation);             
                self.selectedItem().Currency.commit();
                self.selectedItem().Abbreviation.commit();
                self.selectedItem().Amount.commit();
                self.selectedItem().date_borrowed.commit();
                self.selectedItem().monthly_amortization.commit();
                self.selectedItem().lender.commit();
                self.selectedItem().final_due_date.commit();
                self.selectedItem().itemIsEdited(1);
                self.selectedItem(null);
                self.selectedCurrencyLocal(null);
            };

            this.cancelItemEdit = function() {
                self.selectedItem().Currency.reset();
                self.selectedItem().Abbreviation.reset();
                self.selectedItem().Amount.reset();
                self.selectedItem().date_borrowed.reset();
                self.selectedItem().monthly_amortization.reset();
                self.selectedItem().lender.reset();
                self.selectedItem().final_due_date.reset();
                self.selectedItem(null);
                self.selectedCurrencyLocal(null);
            };

            this.templateToUse = function(item) {
                return self.selectedItem() === item ? "RReditTmpl" : "RRitemTmpl";
            };
        };



        /* Function for intializing the UserOpenLoansViewModel, that gets the 
         * open loans data by pushing retrieved open loans to self.userOpenLoan
         * observable variable and by displaying that variable in a modal dialog. */
        self.InitializeUserOpenLoansViewModel = function () {            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/myprofile/getUserOpenLoan/' + auth,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(openloanList) {
                var loanItems = [];
                $.each(openloanList, function (index, loan) {
                    var newLoan = new Item(loan);
                    loanItems[index] = newLoan;
                });
                self.userOpenLoan(new UserOpenLoanViewModel(self, loanItems));
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
                alert( "Initializing the UserOpenLoansViewModel failed. Error code thrown: " + errorThrown);
            })
            .always(function(data){               
            });
        };
```

with all this I call the template and I can add new rows of information or delete them, but I cannot get them to work when I click the button called New Item.

Comment: I think you need `$root.addItem` in your binding, but you've included so much code here it's a little hard to wade through.

Comment: @RoyJ sorry I dint know a proper way of explaining this, but I cannot get my code to run at all, and I dont need to add $root.addItem since the model is opening just that its not getting the data by clicking the button.

Comment: @RoyJ the thing is that the template that is in the starting of this page with <script id="RRitemTmpl" type="text/html"> , that template needs to be called and  it cant find it for some reason.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your template selector is a function, not an observable

```
this.templateToUse = function(item) {
    return self.selectedItem() === item ? "RReditTmpl" : "RRitemTmpl";
};
```

So you need to invoke it, using parentheses:

```
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse(), foreach: items}"></tbody>
```

Comment: Tried it didnt work, I think the mistake is somewhere in the JS file which is the last block of code, which is not being able to call the template.

Comment: There may be many mistakes. There is a lot of code there. You need to make a new, minimal example that does just the template stuff. When you have that working, put other features in.